# PHP ReflectionMethod does not get default boolean value of param

Tags: php, reflection, boolean

When I try to get the value of a boolean param, with ReflectionMethod, that have a default value set, I got empty result.

With this code:

```
    public function GetOrderBook($symbol = null, $limit = 100, $async = false)
    {
        if ($symbol !== null) {

            $params = [];
            $ref = new \ReflectionMethod($this, 'GetOrderBook');

            foreach ($ref->getParameters() as $param) {
                $name = $param->name;
                $params[$name] = $$name;
            }

            print_r($params);
        }
    }
```

I get this:

```
 Array ( 
      [symbol] => ETHBTC 
      [limit] => 100 
      [async] => 
 )
```

Is there a way to get the default value of a param with reflection?

Comment: `[async] => ` means that value of async is `false`, because string representation of `false` is empty string. Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and you will see real values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_r` function outputs **string** representation of values. String representation of `false` is **empty string**. To see real values that you have in an array, use `var_dump`:

```
var_dump($params);
```

After that you will see that:

```
["async"]=>bool(false)
```